# android : linker error with .so file

Tags: android, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am using a library in my app. So i have added the jar file to the libs folder. 
This library usese some native functions. I have the .so files copied under jav/main/jnilibs . There are arm64-v8a,armeabi ,armeabi-v7a,mips,mips64,x86,x86_64 and all has correct .so files.

But i am getting linking error for one function
No implementation found for byte[] com.android.internal.xxx.xxx.FunctionService.functionNative(int, byte[], byte[], byte[]) (tried Java_com_android_internal_xxx_xxx_FunctionService_functionNative and Java_com_android_internal_xxx_xxx_FunctionService_functionNative__I_3B_3B_3B)

What does this error means . How it can be fixed

Answer (score 0):

call to System.loadLibrary was missing. I added it and it worked

[Android NDK C++ JNI (no implementation found for native...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197889/android-ndk-c-jni-no-implementation-found-for-native)