# No implementation found for native code in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, ini

Now Im using ffmpeg java library in android. I want to use it directly in my app, So Im inporting this library. But I have a problem with it.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.softcode.kihnoplay, PID: 15313
              java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String androidFfmpeg.ArmArchHelper.cpuArchFromJNI() (tried Java_androidFfmpeg_ArmArchHelper_cpuArchFromJNI and Java_androidFfmpeg_ArmArchHelper_cpuArchFromJNI__)
                  at androidFfmpeg.ArmArchHelper.cpuArchFromJNI(Native Method)
                  at androidFfmpeg.CpuArchHelper.getCpuArch(CpuArchHelper.java:16)
                  at androidFfmpeg.FFmpeg.loadBinary(FFmpeg.java:40)
                  at com.softcode.tablet.Mp3Concat_Thread.startThread(Mp3Concat_Thread.java:90)
                  at com.softcode.tablet.Mp3Concat_Thread.<init>(Mp3Concat_Thread.java:54)
                  at com.softcode.phone.record.view.RecordActivity.onCreate(RecordActivity.java:182)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

I don't know why this error is occurring.

My directory tree is

[image]
and c file code.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cpu-features.h>

jstring
Java_androidFfmpeg_ArmArchHelper_cpuArchFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject       obj)
{
char arch_info[11] = "";

if (android_getCpuFamily() == ANDROID_CPU_FAMILY_ARM) {
    strcpy(arch_info, "ARM");

    uint64_t cpuFeatures = android_getCpuFeatures();
    if ((cpuFeatures & ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_ARMv7) != 0) {
        strcat(arch_info, " v7");

        if((cpuFeatures & ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_NEON) != 0) {
            strcat(arch_info, "-neon");
        }
    }
}
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, arch_info);
}
```

And this is a grade(app)

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.softcode.kihnoplay"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.00"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a","x86"
    }

    aaptOptions
            {
                cruncherEnabled = false
            }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    jni.srcDirs = [] //important!!!! disable automatic ndk-build call
}
```

I don't know why this error is occurring. If you know this problem please let me know. Thanks you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android NDK C++ JNI (no implementation found for native...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197889/android-ndk-c-jni-no-implementation-found-for-native)

Comment: @VicJordan Thank you... but It's not works.

Comment: `externalNativeBuild {ndkBuild {path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'}}` add this block in your gradle file i hope it will help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using a clang++ compiling c source code, right? If true, try to change your file name to be armArch.cpp and add keyword **extern** into your C header and source files. e.g.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// your function declarations or implementations. 

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Also, i would like to suggest use **externalNativeBuild** and **cmake** block rather than the older **ndk** block which is not the modern convention for Android native builds.  E.g.

```
android {

    //....

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.softcode.kihnoplay"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.00"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64' 
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //....
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

Android NDK has deprecated **armeabi**, you don't actually need to include this ABI is your abiFilters setting. ABIs **'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'** will be enough for supporting almost all the current Android devices as well as emulators.

You can find a comprehensive JNI tutorial from https://arophix.com/2017/12/17/andoid-jni-summary/ 
and a sample JNI project from https://github.com/russell-shizhen/JniExample

Comment: Maybe it's not c++. I just use this library https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java.   I just want to use it with editing some codes.

Comment: I did a quick check on the project ffmpeg-android-java, it is an old Android Studio project which has many older plugins and deprecated gradle closures used. For the native build part, it is actually only one simple file inside which is to check the CPU architecture.

Comment: Probably for your case, using the latest native build pattern, i.e. externalNativeBuild and cmake will be easier.

Comment: Oh, Really appreciate for your favor. So, What I have to do is doing your answer?

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
        classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


changes classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

Comment: also commented out inside build.gradle under FFmpegAndroid  //apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'. Then remove //install { } block, open this project with latest android studio. Then run "CpuArchHelperTest", you will have this test passed.